# Asking the user the same question more than once in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods

Starting my Intro To Programming class and we'll be using C# throughout it. I'm currently writing a practice program to get familiar with C# that asks the user for their name and age and then reads it out to them and asks if it is correct. I want to make it so that if the user wants to change their inputted data for any reason then they can press the "n" key for "no that's not right" and re enter their data. However, I want to re-ask them the questions for their age and name(separately) without having to re-type the code block with the Console.WriteLines and if...else block. I did some research and found that:

1. the "go-to" statement was made by the devil himself and it's essentially the programming equivalent of a hate crime if I use it
2. making a new method (and subsequently calling that method in my code) with the block of code asking the question seems to be the way to go about it.

My problem is that while I've (hopefully) figured out that's what I need to do, I can't seem to figure out how exactly to either implement that method nor call it correctly later on.

here is the method I'm trying to create that I want to hold an "if...else" statement asking if the info is correct, incorrect, or re-ask the question if the enter something other than "y" or "n":

```
public void Question()
{
    Console.Write("Could I get your name? (Press enter when you are done) ");
    string user_name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write("Awesome! Now if you could just enter your age: ");
    string user_age = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("So according to the information I have on file here... you are " + user_name + " and you're " + user_age + " years old....");
}
```

This isn't homework so I don't mind specific pieces of code so I can see how it works and tinker with it to learn :)

Comment: So you want to repeat a question until it was answered sufficiently. One construct to do that is a `while()` loop. Check if your criterium was met,, when it's not just let it repeat by returning true to the `while(condition)` condition

Comment: do ( ask questions; display; ask if correct } while (correct = no)

Comment: Break the problem down - look at your `Question` function...any of that looks repetitive? Wouldn't it be great if you could just call a function with _any_ question string and have it return you any answer input from the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good work on doing some research on your own, and a fairly decent question. And you're on the right track.

So let's first focus on asking the question part. If you look at your `Question()` method, you can see that you're sort of doing the same thing repeatedly inside it. Yes you're asking different questions, but essentially you're doing three things:

- Ask a question.
- Get the answer.
- Clear the Console.

So, maybe you can put those three things into one method, and the only thing that's variable here is the question, so you can pass the question as a parameter.

```
static string AskQuestion(string question)
{
    Console.Write(question);
    var ans = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();
    return ans;
}
```

Alright, a bit better.

Now, how do we repeatedly ask the user a question until we get a satisfactory answer? Loops are a good solution, and particularly either `while` or `do-while` which doesn't iterate a set number of times but rather until a condition is fulfilled. I personally like to use `do-while` in a situation like this.

So what do we have to do there now? Let's break it down. We will write a function, and inside a loop we want to:
 - Ask a question and get the answer. Good thing we have a method that does just that.
 - Show the user the answer he/she entered.
 - Ask the user to confirm if it's good.
 - If yes, terminate the loop, and return the answer.
 - If not, ask the question again.

Something that looks like this:

```
static string GetSatisfactoryAnswer(string question)
{
    var ans = string.Empty;
    bool goodAns = false;
    do
    {
        ans = AskQuestion(question);
        Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}. Is that correct?", ans);
        var confirm = Console.ReadLine();
        if (confirm.ToLower() == "y")
            goodAns = true;
    } while (!goodAns);
    return ans;
}
```

Now you can call them like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var name = GetSatisfactoryAnswer("Could I get your name? (Press enter when you are done) ");
    var age = GetSatisfactoryAnswer("Awesome! Now if you could just enter your age: ");

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Name : {0}", name);
    Console.WriteLine("Age : {0}", age);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

### NOTES

- This is only to give you a rough idea, you'll need to do a lot of error handling. Such as, what if the user enters anything other than `Y/N` for the confirmation?
- It's always a good idea to actually get the age as an integer. So use `int.TryParse()` to convert the `string` input into an `int` and then do something about it if a non-numerical value was entered.
- In your example, you get both `Name` and `Age` at once, then asks use to confirm them later. In my opinion, it's best to finish one thing and start another. In other words, make sure your got a satisfactory answer to `Name`, then move onto `Age`, etc. My answer is designed that way.

Hope this helps. Good luck!